# What is the incidence and the prevalence of symptomatic and asymptomatic tendinopathies for the tendons in the buttock, thigh and iliac regions?

Tags: statistics, tendinopathy

What is the incidence and the prevalence of symptomatic and asymptomatic tendinopathies for each tendon in the buttock, thigh and iliac regions?

---

What I have found so far for yearly symptomatic tendinopathy incidence:

- Achilles: 2.35/1,000 {1}
- Patellar: 1.6/1,000 {1}
- Adductor: 1.22/1,000 {1}
- Gluteal: 4.22/1,000 {1}
- Plantar Fascia: 2.44/1,000 {1}
- Elbow: 3/1,000 {1}
- Shoulder: 3/1,0003/1,000 {1}

The issue is that this list is incomplete and vague (e.g., there are more than one tendon in the glutei).

---

References:

- {1} Dry Needling for Tendinopathy 1.16.18 - Academy of Orthopaedics https://www.orthopt.org/uploads/content_files/files/Dry%20Needling%20for%20Tendinopathy%201.16.18.pdf  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190406233117/https://www.orthopt.org/uploads/content_files/files/Dry%20Needling%20for%20Tendinopathy%201.16.18.pdf))

Comment: I'm still interested in this question.

Comment: If anyone has any idea, comments/answers welcome!